# Apache Beam Pipeline - Serialization problem

Tags: java, apache-beam

My Beam pipeline seems to work properly, but produces a lot of warnings:

```
[direct-runner-worker] WARN org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MutationDetectors - Coder of type class org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.SerializableCoder has a #structuralValue method which does not return true when the encoding of the elements is equal. Element com.emarsys.dataflow.templates.MetricBundle@73d85187
```

The class looks like this:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class MetricBundle implements Serializable {
    private Long customerId;
    private String query;
    private Map<PrimaryKey, Metric> metrics;
}
```

The problem is with the `Map`. `PrimaryKey` and `Metric` classes are composed of simple types, and implement the `Serializable` interface.

The transform producing the `PCollection<MetricBundle>` is using `.setCoder(SerializableCoder.of(MetricBundle.class));`

Do I have to implement a custom coder in order to serialize `Map` properly?
During testing, I found no conflicts in the result, all elements are handled properly.

Answer (score 2):

This is warning that due to the use of SerializableCoder it's not able to check certain properties of your pipeline. (SerializableCoder is also very inefficient.) I would recommend using a more specific coder here, but you don't have to necessarily write one of your own. E.g. it looks like you could decorate your class with `@DefaultSchema(JavaFieldSchema.class)`. See https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#schemas

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try it. Two things to mention:
I'm almost always useing AvroCoder, but it failed because Map doesnt have a noarg constructor.

The warnings only appear on the local runner. I tested it on Dataflow, and it doesnt show any warnings. Still, I'd like to eliminate these.